# Problems with installation ipython notebook in anaconda

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I got some problems with installation ipython notebook / jupyter notebook in anaconda.

Actually, the problem started when I tried to install python 3.4 kernel in 2.7 anaconda. I failed to do that and just installed anaconda 3.4 instead. After that I realized that jupyter notebook for python 3.4 doesn't work and gives kernel error. I somehow managed to fix it by re-intalling anaconda 3.4.

Recently I tried to upgrade anaconda 3.4 and something went wrong. The upgrade terminated with ton of exceptions, and ipython stopped working again.

I tried to re-install anaconda 3.4 (to version 3.5), but it it didn't help. After that I re-installed both versions 2.7 and 3.5, but no result again. Instead intallation of 2.7 went with an error.

Now the situation is:
Anaconda 2.7 installed with an error, but it works somehow (including jupyter).
In anaconda 3.5 jupyter fails to create new puthon3 file with kernel error (see the error log in the end).

It seems to me that I did some stupid thing and I have no idea how to fix it. I want to make both versions of pyhon work (especially notebooks). I'll be thankfull for any help with this situation. OS is Windows 7 Professional.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 458, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 58, in post
    sm.create_session(path=path, kernel_name=kernel_name))
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 73, in create_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 282, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 87, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 109, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 244, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 190, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 108, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Anaconda_3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Comment: If you want both Python 3 and 2 in Anaconda, install Anaconda for one and then create a new environment inside Anaconda with the other version of Python. If you've got Anaconda with Python 2 working, create a Python 3 environment with `conda create -n py3 python=3`. It will tell you how to activate and deactivate that environment.